# Unchanged handler gets notified when using with_items

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible play that changes configuration files of services and restarts services that had their configuration changed. I do this by notifying handler.
For some reason program that had no changes gets also restarted by handler.

Running the play when only Program 1 has changes:

```
TASK [programs : Configure programs] **********************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1] => (item=program1)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=program2)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=program3)

RUNNING HANDLER [programs : Restart program1] ****************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]

RUNNING HANDLER [programs : Restart program2] **************************************
changed: [127.0.0.1]
```

Handler file of role:

```
- name: Restart program1
  service:
    name: program1
    state: restarted

- name: Restart program2
  service:
    name: program2
    state: restarted

- name: Restart program3
  service:
    name: program3
    state: restarted
```

Task for changing configuration:

```
- name: Configure programs
  template:
    src: templates/{{ item }}.conf.j2
    dest: '{{ install_path }}/{{ item }}/{{ item }}.conf'
  notify: 'Restart {{ item }}'
  with_items: '{{ list_of_programs }}'
```

Why does restart of Program2 get notified without any change?

I am using `ansible 2.0.0.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works for current ansible versions.

**All** notified handlers will be executed if **any** of the items has changed state.

See this [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22579) and upvote it if you think this is undesired behaviour.

Comment: In my case all handlers are not getting executed only some of them. (Program3 in my example did not get executed.)

Comment: You can inspect/debug pieces of code provided in the linked issue to troubleshoot your issue. I'm just saying that this is to be expected from ansible to run multiple handlers bound to looped task.